# Unable to open object (bad object header version number)' when I used load_model to load the .h5 file

Tags: keras, model, h5py

When I used `load_model` from `keras.models` to load the trained model, which is a `.h5` file. The errors happened:

```sh
KeyError: 'Unable to open object (bad object header version number)'.
```

But the `h5py` works well.

Comment: you wrote **.55** is it a mistake or did you have that extension on the file ? Also, could you provide the code of where you saved the model ?

Comment: I used `ModelCheckpoint('model.h5',monitor='val_acc',save_best_only=True') ` to save to model.

Comment: I faced the same issue while I was opening a `.h5` file in `tables` (version 3.6.1). However, there is no issue when I rename the file to `.h5py`.